# How to create a copy of data when the data has a hierarchy

Tags: sql-server

I have a table structure where there are FK columns in child tables.

So say there is the following:

```
Company
-company_id
-name

Location
-location_id
-company_name
-name

Store
-store_id
-location_id
-name

Inventory
-inventory_id
-store_id
```

Now I want to create a copy of a company, along with all of location, store and inventory rows.

So say I want to create a copy of company_id=123, I have to duplicate all the rows.

I tried this:

```
DECLARE @OriginalCompanyId = 123

DECALRE @companyId AS INT

INSERT Companies (name)
select c.name 
from companies c
where c.companyId = @OrignalCOmpanyId

SET @companyId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

But this approach won't work because the other tables have multiple rows and I won't be able to linkup the newly inserted PK values.

What approach should I be taking?

Comment: that doesn't make sense

Comment: @PouriaSharif what doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I've actually been working on a project that does just this. My solution while not fancy, has so far proven effective.. the annoying part being the setup process. I am very open to critique and suggestions for improvement.

1. Create a "mirror" schema/db of all the necessary tables (I've gone with New[ApplicationTableName])
2. For each pKey/fKey, create a "placeholder" column (I've gone with p[ColumnName])
3. Map the existing data to placeholder keys, indexed at 1. (This is annoying, but doable with ranking functions.)
4. Insert into the application by your placeholder keys in descending order (descending is important!)
5. Update your "mirror" table using ranking functions (see example)
6. Repeat as necessary using the drived/inserted values across however many tables you need.

Example:

Given this schema...

```
CREATE TABLE Accounts (
    AccountID int identity(1,1) not null,
    Name varchar(500) not null

)

CREATE TABLE Users(
    UserID int identity(1,1) not null,
    AccountID int not null,
    Name varchar(500) not null
)

CREATE TABLE NewUsers(
    pUserID int not null,
    UserID int not null,
    AccountID int not null,
    Name varchar(500)
)
```

And this data

```
INSERT INTO NewUsers VALUES
(1,0,0,'Bob'),
(2,0,0,'Sally'),
(3,0,0,'Jeff'),
(4,0,0,'Sam')
```

Say for each time we "create" an account we want to create these 4 default users... This will look something like this

```
DECLARE @AccountID int --this is scalar, so we'll use scope_identity() to grab it.
INSERT INTO Account VALUES('MyNewAccountID')
SELECT @AccountID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

--Prepare NewUsers w/ derived accountID
UPDATE NewUsers SET AccountID = @AccountID

--Do our "application" insert
INSERT INTO Users(AccountID,Name)

SELECT AccountID,Name
FROM NewUsers
ORDER BY pUserID DESC;

--Capture inserted ID's for use in other tables (where we've derived pUserID)
WITH InsertedUsers AS(
    SELECT
        --use dense rank, it handles fkey mappings too
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY UserID DESC) as pUserID,
        UserID
    FROM Users
)
UPDATE NewUsers SET UserID = iu.UserID
FROM NewUsers nu
JOIN InsertedUsers iu
ON iu.pUserID = nu.pUserID


SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Account ORDER BY 1 DESC
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Users ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

So now if a future table needs UserID into the app (and has a derived pUserID,) we can grab it from NewUsers by joining on pUserID.